# *.tar.gz file download use apache2 webserver

Tags: django, apache, gzip

I would like to implement a function that user can upload/download file.
 But when user upload a *tar.gz file and download, seems the file was changed, file's md5sum was changed and the files size was chaged. 
Productions env use apache webserver. The webframework is django,
It's seems django's develop webserver  upload/download *tar.gz file is okay (the file will not changed). 
Is relate to apache server? any suggestions?

Comment: j4i: tested with debian squeeze, python2.7, django1.4, apache2 - same md5. sorry couldn't help

Comment: Post the code of your upload functionality. I guess download simply happens via a html link?